# Can we use MultiProcessing or MultiThreading in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, multiprocessing, p5.js

I am currently working on a project that requires me to execute parallel processes but I can't find any way to do it in p5.js. Could someone help me with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p5 itself seems to be pretty tightly tied to the web page that you load it in, and the browser environment is such that only a single JavaScript thread can directly interact with that page. But if you have a lot of non-drawing number crunching to do, you can do that using *web workers* ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)). A web worker is a separate thread, isolated from the thread interacting with the web page, that can run in parallel with it and communicate with it via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and (in some environments) [shared memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer). (See [this note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer/Planned_changes) on changes to shared memory to deal with Spectre and Meltdown; I also go into detail on that in my new book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*, in Chapter 16. Links in my profile if you're interested.)